# Is it possible to have mysql treat row based updates as "upserts"?

Tags: mysql, replication

When processing row based replication events, mysql replication will break if it's unable to find a row matching the "before image".

Is there any setting to tell mysql, if you don't find that row, just create it?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) or [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html) statements on the master server.

Just **note** that:

- These are **unsafe statements for replication**, so statement based replication will produce a warning and divergence is possible - consider using **MIXED** bin log.
- These only work on tables with a **single unique key or primary key**
- If there are differences in **auto-increment primary key** columns, the statements will update divergent records (hence the unsafe classification) (see the manual)

Comment: The scenario I was talking about was using straight row based replication, hence the "before image" it's using.